# UPDATE statement GA4 Big Query SQL with events and UNNEST

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to find a way to update records that have a event_name page_view and key page_location where the latter is containing some pattern. The query below gives me the selection I'm after. Now the problem is that I cannot wrap my head around how to include and UPDATE statement to change the values of page_location in that selection. Do you know?

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
SELECT (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE event_name = 'page_view' AND key = 'page_location') AS page 
FROM `project-name.analytics_299XXXXXX.events_*`
WHERE 
  _table_suffix BETWEEN '20220322'
  AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AND
event_name = 'page_view'
 LIMIT 1000
) x
WHERE x.page LIKE '%login%';
```

Comment: What are you trying to update exactly? Do you have an expected output?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly i think you should use the following pattern. Google [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#update_statement) don't have this update pattern listed which is a shame as it's the most useful IMO:

```
update ds.targettable t
set t.targetfield = s.sourcefield
from (select keyfield, sourcefield
      from ds.sourcetable 
) s
where t.keyfield = s.keyfield
```

I apologize in advance as I don't have access to the GA events table so i've just coded this up from the top of my head; here is some code that should get you close:

```
update `project-name.analytics_299XXXXXX.events_*` tgt
set page_location = src.page
from (SELECT event_name, key, _table_suffix (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE event_name = 'page_view' AND key = 'page_location') AS page 
      FROM `project-name.analytics_299XXXXXX.events_*`
      WHERE _table_suffix BETWEEN '20220322'
            AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) 
            AND event_name = 'page_view'
            and page LIKE '%login%') src
 --join tables together on PK (or make one)
where farm_fingerprint(concat(tgt.key, tgt.event_name) = farm_fingerprint(concat(src.key, src.event_name)
and src._table_suffix = tgt._table_suffix
and tgt.page LIKE '%login%'
```

*I'm not exactly sure how to manage the table suffix so you may need to play with that*

Comment: Thanks for getting in touch. When running the query I get: Each function argument is an expression, not a query; to use a query as an expression, the query must be wrapped with additional parentheses to make it a scalar subquery expression at [3:46] The editor seems to have a problem with the second SELECT on line three.

Comment: maybe just try to simplify your query a bit:
1. remove the farm_fingerprint from the join and use the PK? I see i've left off a couple of brackets.
2. remove the table_suffix and wildcard and just try to get the update to work on a single table.
Basically start with the templated pattern and then build it up once running.

Comment: Hi again. I struggle to follow your suggestions. Could you please advice how to create the query?

Comment: can you post a create table statement with some sample rows inserted for the table you wish to update (i.e. `analytics_299XXXXXX.events_xxxxx`) then can write the an update statement against that, not having the actual table makes it difficult debug. cheers